# How to update immutable values in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have collection like this.

```
const Device: Schema = new Schema(
{
  location: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  macAddress: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      immutable: true,
    },
  ip: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      immutable: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
    collection: 'Device',
  }
);
```

I want to update immutable fields with my endpoints and i use this function and doesnt work.

```
Device.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.mdeviceId },
    { $set: { macAddress: req.body.macAddress, ip: req.body.ip},
    { new: true, upsert: true }
  );
```

How can i update this specific fields?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess `req.params.mdeviceId` is a string and needs to be casted to `ObjectId`, this is not related to the `immutable` property as you are providing the `new` flag which allows to bypass the schema protection, try using this:

```
Device.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.mdeviceId) },
    { $set: { macAddress: req.body.macAddress, ip: req.body.id},
    { new: true, upsert: true }
);
```

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't work

Comment: does the update itself succeed? does the updateat field get updated?

Comment: Update is succeed, updateAt field still changed but ip or macAddress field doesnt updated.